How to make a custom 'dynamic' route according to the request header?
I want to make a custom route, which is like this: A request with a header to:221.221.221.221 sends to the gateway such as '133.113.113.133', and it is blocked by the gateway, gateway should check this request's header to:221.221.221.221, and send this request to the 221.221.221.221.
What should I do?
I tried to figure out this problem by writing my own 'dynamic' route like underneath.
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: custom_route
          uri: http://{ hostname }:15412
          predicates:
            - Header=co, {hostname}

        - id: custom_route
          uri: http://{ hostnameAndPort }
          predicates:
            - Header=co, { hostnameAndPort }

and
@Bean
public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String newUri = request.getHeader("newUri");
    return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
        .route(r -> r.uri(newUri))
        .build();
}

It still doesn't work. What should I do to solve this problem?
